# python 3: splitting information and reporting occurrences

Tags: python

Say for example i want to count how many times bob visits sears and walmart how would i do this by creating dictionaries?

```
information given:
bob:oct1:sears
bob:oct1:walmart
mary:oct2:walmart
don:oct2:sears
bob:oct4:walmart
mary:oct4:sears
```

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it as such.   Homework hint:  The CSV reader takes an optional delimiter argument such as ``delimiter=':'``.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, as this might be homework, I’ll try to give you some hints on how to do this. If this is not homework, please say so, and I’ll restore my original answer and example code.

So first of all, you have your data set in a way that each entry is in single line. As we want to work with each data entry on its own, we have to split the original data into each lines. We can use `str.split` for that.

Each entry is constructed in a simple format `name:date:location`. So to get each of those segments again, we can use `str.split` again. Then we end up with separated content for each entry.

To store this, we want to sort the data by the *name* first. So we choose a dictionary taking the name as the key, and put in the visits as the data. As we don’t care about the date, we can forget about it. Instead we want to count how often a single location occurs for a given name. So what we do, is keep another dictionary using the locations as the key and the visit count as the data. So we end up with a doubled dictionary, looking like this:

```
{
    'bob': {
        'sears': 1,
        'walmart': 1,
    },
    'mary': {
        ...
    }
}
```

So to get the final answers we just look into that dictionary and can immediately read out the values.

Comment: Sorry that i didn't specify it isn't homework just a practice exercise  from the textbook.

Answer (score 0):

[@poke provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7987123/python-3-splitting-information-and-reporting-occurrences/7987387#7987387) a nice explanation, here's a corresponding code:

#### Read input from files provided on command-line or stdin and dump occurrences in json format:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import csv
import fileinput
import json
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

visits = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
for name, _, shop in csv.reader(fileinput.input(), delimiter=':'): 
    visits[name][shop] += 1

# pretty print
json.dump(visits, sys.stdout, indent=2)
```

#### Output

```
{
  "bob": {
    "sears": 1, 
    "walmart": 2
  }, 
  "don": {
    "sears": 1
  }, 
  "mary": {
    "sears": 1, 
    "walmart": 1
  }
}
```

This representation allows easily to find out how many visits and where a person had.

If you always know both name and location then you could use a simpler representation:

```
visits = defaultdict(int)
for name, _, shop in csv.reader(fileinput.input(), delimiter=':'):
    visits[name,shop] += 1

print(visits['bob','walmart'])
# -> 2
```